# Looking for an alternative to MAX(COUNTIF(Range, Criteria)) that can ignore white-space

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I currently have an excel formula that can search a comma separated list string contained in a cell and determine whether that cell contains another exact string as an element.

The formula is: `MAX(COUNTIF(A1,{"*,";""}&B1&{"",",*"}))`

The formula behaves, *correctly*, like so:

```
A            B        Result    Comment
1,2,3        1        1         1 exists in 1,2,3
1,2,3        2        1         2 exists in 1,2,3
A,B,C        C        1         C exists in A,B,C
A,B,C        Z        0         Z does not exist in A,B,C
123,456,789  5        0         5 does not exist in 123,456,789
```

The problem I've encountered with this is that the formula fails as soon as whitespace is introduced. Since `COUNTIF` must be passed a range as it's first parameter, I cannot simply use:

```
SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")
```

I'd also prefer, if at all possible, not to use any extraneous cells to hold the whitespace eliminated string.

It would be very simple to write a function in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to do this, but as this spreadsheet is to be distributed to end-users (who might inadvertently disable macros), this is not an ideal solution.

**Does anyone know of any alternative formula to the one proposed above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SEARCH("," & B1 & ",", "," & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","") & ",")
```

but this approach will fail if any of your strings to be found contain spaces

Comment: This perfectly suits my use-case, but may not suit all cases (cases where desired string contains a space, as you point out). I will think on this point further (as something reusable is my ultimate goal). In any case, you have my thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1,1))=TRUE,"Text True","Text false")
```

Does this solve your problem? It searches the text from column A and return text result.

Comment: Unfortunately not, as this will find "5" in "123,456,789" as it is present as a substring of "456".